# There has been blocked for additions to the site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, console-application, stsadm

I am trying to execute a console application which updates creation dates on specified items in sharepoint lists.

When I try to execute I get this error:

> There has been blocked for additions to the site. Contact system administrator to solve the problem.

I then went to the Central Administration to check if Quotas and Locks was set to Not Locked. Then afterwards running the stsadm commando

> stsadm -o getsitelock -url http://mysite

Which returned **SiteLock Lock="none"**, so those 2 matched.

I have debugged the console application and made it console.writeline each step it takes and it gets to the item.update(); part and that's when I get the above message.

Do you guys know another way around to solve this issue?

Comment: Whoever wrote that error message should be shot by a grammar Nazi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gone through  all solutions provided [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/erobillard/archive/2007/10/31/error-quot-additions-to-this-web-site-have-been-blocked-quot.aspx) ?

or

check the document library settings and found out that doc. library was set NOT to require check out although versioning was enabled. just try to set to require check out

Answer (score 0):

i dont know this is the right solution but i have faced the same problem and i did restart my machine and the problem is resolved.

hope this trick work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your database read-only.